# Trying to solve a trig identity

Tags: trigonometry

Given $\sin 2x+\sin x=1$, find the value of $\cos 2x+\cos 4x$.

I know $\cos 2x+\cos 4x \implies 1-2\sin^2x+1-2\sin^22x$, but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Is that related to the software _Mathematica_?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to solve the first expression for `x` and plug in to the second expression.

```
result = 
 FullSimplify[
  Cos[4 x] + Cos[2 x] /. 
   Solve[{Sin[2 x] + Sin[x] - 1 == 0}, x, Reals], 
  Assumptions -> Element[C[1], Integers]]

(* {0, Root[-32 + 29 #1 + 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]} *)

N[result]

(* {0., 0.907353} *)
```

If you do not restrict to real `x` then the other two roots of that cubic are aslo solutions for this.

Comment: For those that prefer expressions with radicals rather than root objects, use `result // ToRadicals`

Answer (score 0):

$\sin2x~=~2\sin x\cos x\quad=>\quad\underbrace{\sin2x+\sin x}_1~=~\sin x~(2\cos x+1).\quad$ Squaring, we have

$\sin^2x~(2\cos x+1)^2=1\iff(1-\cos^2x)(2\cos x+1)^2=1,~$ which, after letting $t=\cos x$,

becomes $t~(4t^3+4t^2-3t-4)=0.~$ Now, $t=0\iff x=\dfrac\pi2$ is definitely a solution, the other

one being the only real root of the cubic, whose expression can be found using *Mathematica's* Solve

function. See [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for more details.

---

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]